# how can i make the hero jump up and to feel the gravity

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem making my character jump and feel the ground. This is  my player code. My screen properties are `width=155` and `height=55`. The character should start at the top and go down and up.

```
void MoveHeroPosition(int &rH, int &cH, char Q, int &dY)
{
    if (rH < 15)
    {
        rH += dY;
        if (dY < 1)
        {
            dY++; 
        }
    }

    if ( Q == 'a' )
    {
        cH--;

    }

    if ( Q == 'd')
    {
        cH++;
    }

    if ( Q == 'v')
    {
        dY = -3; 
        if (dY < 1)
        {
            dY++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `void main()
{
 char X[55][155];
 int dY = 0;
 int rH = 11;
 int cH = 46;
 int rf =17;
 int cf= 5;

 int rE = 4, cE=30;
 for (;;)
 {
  for (;    !_kbhit() ;)
  {
   FillX(X);
   fillmap(X,20,50,50,78,1,24,24,24,60,30,33,60,33,60,60,60,70,1,20);
   fillmap(X,105,135,78,105,131,154,131,91,131,125,90,125,94,122,90,83,90,135,154);
   FillHeroInX( X , rH , cH);
   //MoveHeroPosition( rH, cH);
   
            
  
   Disp(X);
   char Q;
      Q = _getch(); // cin>>Q;
      MoveHeroPosition( rH , cH, Q,dY);
  }
 }
}
`

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61572026/edit) your question to add additional detail rather than adding comments. Please provide a [mre]. What is the problem with the code you've posted?